# Save data from multiple inputs from html webpage as .txt (locally) and load them back at the same places

Tags: javascript, html, input, save

I am a young programming learner with 3-4 weeks of experience in html/css and JS.

I am making an extremely simple HTML page,putting inputs and manipulate those inputs using plain JavaScript.

The nature of this project is for someone to type stuff in a form with text type inputs and get automatic calculations between them (stuff that duplicate in other places,add,subtract,multiply,appear in printable areas elsewhere and generally a lot of different small operations).

I have no trouble developing such a small idea with the minimal knowledge that i have at the moment and learning on the way!

Now that I am almost near the completion of what I have in my mind, I want a method to save the data from all the different inputs in my html, close the browser (so no session storage and local storage solutions is applied (?) and then load them back to the same places as they were,so someone can continue working on the same "form" and not having to re-enter all the different data to the inputs.

I know that something like this can be conducted in a simple Excel spreadsheet, and I know that different programming languages has to be used and probably server communication etc.

At the moment I need this be completed with JS script within HTML content.

I have found a seemingly very popular piece of an 8 year old code, which manages to save the data from 1 input to a .txt file (locally) and is also able to load back those data to the same input from the saved .txt file.

https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

https://thiscouldbebetter.neocities.org/texteditor.html

```
<html>
<body>
 
<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
        <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
    </tr>
</table>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
 
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 
    downloadLink.click();
}
 
function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
 
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
 
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
 
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The creator of this piece was asked if it was possible for someone to modify it and make it possible to save multiple inputs in 1 .txt and he replied its possible if you put your inputs within a "class", therefore create an array of all of them and then get all of their inputs using a for loop :

> Okay, so it’s really hard to give HTML code examples in these
> comments, because WordPress handles them out unpredictably. But
> basically, replace the single textarea element from the code in the
> article with a bunch of inputs that all have the same class, for
> example, “inputTextToSave”. Then replace the first line of the
> saveTextAsFile() function with these lines:
>
> var textToWrite = “”; var inputsTextToSave =
> document.getElementsByClassName(“inputTextToSave”); for (var i = 0; i
> < inputsTextToSave.length; i++) { var inputTextToSave =
> inputsTextToSave[i]; var textFromInput = inputTextToSave.value;
> textToWrite += textFromInput; }

I tried to modify not only my own code to make it work, but his code as well and I cannot seem to make it get the data of more than 1 input to a single .txt and load it back.

I was hoping that if i modify his code successfully then I would have the workframe to work on mine as well.

How can I make the modification to the above code in order to save multiple inputs and load them back at the same input "boxes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with storing data from multiple sources into one file is that upon loading you don't know which portion of that pile of data belongs to what. Well you even don't know that it might be data from multiple sources.

To get around this we need to store some additional information in the text file which we can use to distinct the different text blocks.

A simple way is programmatically adding a delimiter in-between - a character or a sequence of characters your user most likely won't ever use.

Say we have three text boxes:

```
TextBox 1: Here is
TextBox 2: some
TextBox 3: text
```

If we combine those textes and add a delimiter `_*_`

it will turn into `Here is_*_some_*_text`

Now we can use the `string.split("_*_")` method which splits the input string at `_*_` and returns an array `["Here is","some","text"]` which we can use to populate the textboxes.

Here's an example (Just click 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var separator = "_*_";
var textBoxes = ["inputTextToSave1", "inputTextToSave2"];

function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToSave = "";
  for (var a = 0; a < textBoxes.length; a++) {
    textToSave += a < textBoxes.length - 1 ? document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value + separator : document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value;
  }
  var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
    type: "text/plain"
  });
  var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
  var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText() {
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    var textesArray = textFromFileLoaded.split(separator);
    for (var a = 0; a < textBoxes.length; a++) {
      document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value = textesArray[a];
    }
  };
  fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text to Save:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <textarea id="inputTextToSave1" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <textarea id="inputTextToSave2" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
    <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></td>
    <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious time !!
For some reason this snippet works only in FF but this is fine,i can run it there,no issues.
I will try to implement you piece into my code and see what happens!!

Comment: Glad I could help nospipi! If you think this is the correct answer please consider accepting it using the tick button. By the way I see no reason why it should just work in FireFox. If you're original script has worked in others, this should work too. Maybe it's just the interactive snippet above but the code itself is fine. I've just tested it in Chrome.